# Decreasing size of the corners when maximizing window - winapi c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to make a program with a custom design. I got rid of the default window header using the code below

```
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        RECT WindowRect;
        int x, y;

        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &WindowRect);
        x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam) - WindowRect.left;
        y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) - WindowRect.top;

        if (x >= borderWidth && x <= WindowRect.right - WindowRect.left - borderWidth && y >= borderWidth && y <= TITLEBARHEIGHT) {
            return HTCAPTION;
        }
        else if (x < borderWidth && y < borderWidth)
            return HTTOPLEFT;
        else if (x > WindowRect.right - WindowRect.left - borderWidth && y < borderWidth)
            return HTTOPRIGHT;
        else if (x > WindowRect.right - WindowRect.left - borderWidth && y > WindowRect.bottom - WindowRect.top - borderWidth)
            return HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
        else if (x < borderWidth && y > WindowRect.bottom - WindowRect.top - borderWidth)
            return HTBOTTOMLEFT;
        else if (x < borderWidth)
            return HTLEFT;
        else if (y < borderWidth)
            return HTTOP;
        else if (x > WindowRect.right - WindowRect.left - borderWidth)
            return HTRIGHT;
        else if (y > WindowRect.bottom - WindowRect.top - borderWidth)
            return HTBOTTOM;
        else
            return HTCLIENT;
        return false;
```

I drew my own header with my own buttons such as: close window, maximize and minimize window. So, everything works well but when I am maximizing the window it cuts off some of the corner,(I am maximizing window with the following code SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);)

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, do I need to adjust the window rectangle when I am maximizing the window or something else?

Here are some images that show the issue I'm talking about, on the first picture is how it looks before maximizing, and the second picture is maximized. You can see on the second picture the corners are cut off.

[image: Before maximizing]

[image: After maximizing]

Comment: You mentioned you custom draw all of your icons, hit boxes, captions, etc. I suspect the problem lays there. A "maximized" window does *not* normally render sizing borders (well, duh; the window is maximized). Your maximized version, at least from what I see, seems to suggest that additional magnitude (or lack of it) may be what is causing this. Caveat: I've done plenty of custom NC drawing in Windows, but never had to go as full-steam into it as you're doing now, so I give it at-most a 50/50 chance I'm talking out of an alternate body orifice, but maybe worth a look at nonetheless.

Comment: Maximized windows extend beyond the edges of the screen. You need to compensate for this when doing your custom drawing. See [Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150304-00/?p=44543) for more information.